# grey line I don't know where it come from after adding search bar

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in coding, and I have to create a website for a school project. I tried to resolve the problem myself but it just don't work.

I wanted to add a search bar to my website so I followed a tutorial, and it worked on a blank new html page, but when I copied paste on my html page project I have this lightgray frame that comes around the search bar , where does it come from and what to delete/change ? thank you :)

```css
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : 01-mars-2017, 14:52:23
    Author     : jonathan
*/
/* syling my paragraphs */
div {
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    
}

  

body {
    
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color:  white;

}
p {
    color: darkgreen;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:Arial;
    }
    
    .highlight {
        
        color:darkgray;
    }
    
    /* styling navigation */
    #search {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 7px;
        
        
    }
    #submit {
        padding: 7px;
        background: #669999;
        
        color: white;
        margin-letf: -5px;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    #submit:hover {
        background:#333;
        transition: all 0.40s;
    }
    
    
    
    
    .header-logo {
        display:block;
        height:240px;
        width:240px;
        background:url(images/wolf.png) no-repeat;
        text-indent:50%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
        
   
    }
   
    nav {
        
        border-bottom:2px solid black;
        border-bottom-color: #669999;
        
    }
    li{
        display:inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right:20px;
       
    }
    
   
    
    nav a:link, nav a:visited {
        color:gray;
        font-size:15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav a:hover {
        background-color: #99ddff;
    }
    
    nav a:active {
        background-color: yellow
    }
    
   
    
    
    
    /* Bordered form */
form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

/* Full-width inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Extra style for the cancel button (red) */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the avatar image inside this container */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

/* Avatar image */
img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

/* The "Forgot password" text */
span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        
        <title> HTML by Jo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="I by mistake deleted all the files 
              so i'm starting all over again">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="wolf.css">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- navigation -->
         
        <header>
        <h1>
            <a class="header-logo" href="http://localhost:8383/Grey%20wolf/index.html"></a>
            
            
        </h1>
             
        </header>
      
        <nav>
            <div style="text-align:center">
            <ul> 
                 <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li> 
               
                
                
            </ul></div>
              <form action="https://google.com">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="20" id="search">
            <input type="submit" value="Go!" id="submit">
            
        </form>
        </nav>
        
        <!-- the content -->
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        
        
        <p>Here is a paragraph.</p>
     
        <p class="highlight">Another paragraph.</p>
        
        <h3 class="highlight">this is a heading h3</h3>
            
        <a href="https://www.codecademy.com/" target="_blank">link to codeacademy</a>
        
             
    </body>
    
     
</html>
```

Comment: try using parent element , `nav form{
        border: 0;
    }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you even taken a look to your CSS? It's fairly commented

```
/* Bordered form */
form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: He have mentioned that he is just a beginner - give him some time and he will be great developer :)

Comment: Being a beginner doesn't mean you're blind to read or investigate about a thing that is very obvious. Also, like i said, the CSS is commented.

Answer (score 1):

Your **form** has this property set there:

```
form{
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

To fix it change it to:

```
form{
    border: 0;
}
```

or try using the `parent element` which is the better way to go,

```
nav form{
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers it works  :) 
I tried to modify the different borders but I have actually not seen that one :/

and now I try to add pictures but the browser doesn't show them what should I do ?

I place this before a paragraph :

```
    <img src="images/model1.jpg" alt="model women 1">
    <img src="images/model2.jpg" alt="model women 2">
    <img src="images/model3.jpg" alt="model women 3">
```

Comment: no its ok I solve it , i don't know really how but great :)

Answer (score -2):

It appears to be the border of `nav`. Try the following CSS:

```
nav {
 border-bottom: none;
}
```